# File Bug for not-completed Product-Backlog-Item?

Tags: tfs, scrum, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-workitem

We are using TFS 2013 and the latest Scrum template.
From my understanding, bugs and PBIs are at the same level in the backlog.

But how to handle bugs/issues, that are found during a sprint in a "ready-for-test" PBI?

When a developer finishes a PBI, he moves it in the Kanban-Board from "*In Progress*" to "*Ready For Test*".

Then our Testers test this PBI (user-story) using Microsofts Test-Manager. When they find an issue, the create a new bug. The advantage of doing so, is that we get a good documentation of the observed problem automatically in the bug work-item.

But from my point of view, it's not a bug. It's simply an unfinished PBI!

The main problem with this approach is, that it's cluttering up the Kanban-board and the backlog very quickly.

What is best practice in that case? 
Is there somewhere a guideline / whitepaper for this scenario?

Or maybe we are just using the Test-Manager in the wrong way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about project management; not software development.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree that what you have is an unfinished PBI.  Where I think things may be going wrong is when the developer effectively 'hands the PBI over' for testing.

Handover, or sign-off, or 'passing the baton' are unhelpful in an agile or Scrum way of working. I advise that focus should always be on moving a single PBI to done. Nothing else matters. Only when that PBI is done, should the developer start work on another PBI.

So, I'd encourage the developer to do whatever it takes to get the PBI tested immediately before he/she starts work on anything else. If any issues arise, the developer addresses it immediately. That way you avoid the situation you describe.

Comment: I agree - more or less - but still: I want the tester to document what's wrong with the PBI and wonder how to do this with the Microsoft tools (TFS and Test-Manager).

Comment: I agree with this answer. In answer to your question we create a new task within the PBI. It's not a 'bug' as such, but it is a piece of work that needs to happen before the story is done.

Comment: @SpoonerNZ has the best solution I think. If the PBI has not met Done then it cant have a bug 

Comment: That's my opinion, too! 
The remaining question is, how to use Test-Manager to store documentation (Screenshot, Video) of the "Not-Done" PBI without creating a bug workitem??

Comment: @ThomasMutzl I'm not sure why would you do that (use Test Manager to store documentation of the "Not-Done" PBI)? I would ask what value  it delivers? My approach would be to simply fix the bug and move on to the next PBI and deliver more value for your stakeholders.

Comment: Test Manager creates a lot of useful info about the "problem" (e.g. Browser version, Screenshots, etc.). Not much effort for the tester & easy to reproduce for the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new task within the PBI. To me, a bug has to be found in 'done' work - while the story is in development, it is just another piece of development that needs to happen before the story is done.

(I have duplicated my comment into an answer as people seem to agree).

Comment: Thanks for commenting again!
But my main point is the tester <-> developer collaboration. I believe a tester should NOT create a new task for developer, as a task is more technical related. He should "just" explain and document why the PBI is not done when he found a defect. IMO creating a dev.task should be in someone else responsibility.

Anyway - if a tester could create a task (instead of a bug) that contains all the needed information directly from test manager, it would be fine for me. But it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

We created a new type of work item called Story Bug, which is based on Task. That is a bug in a story to difference it from a regular bug found outside the work of a story.

We also created for it a slightly different workflow: new -> in progress -> bug resolved -> bug in QA -> done.

The QA opens the story bug in the new state. Then the developer moves it to in progress and when he Finnish working on it he moves it to bug resolved. Then the QA takes it and moves it to bug in QA where he checks that the bug was fixed. If the bug was fixed the QA moves it to done; if not he moves it again to new.